# DMX problem with fonts

Tags: xorg, xfs

I have problem with fonts in xdmx:

I am starting new X

```
startx -- /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx :1 -display 192.168.0.104:0 -fontpath tcp/192.168.0.102:7100


    (II) dmx: Generation:         1
    (II) dmx: DMX version:        1.2.20070424 (DMX Project)
    (II) dmx: DMX Build OS:       Linux 2.6.32-5-686-bigmem i686 (Debian)
    (II) dmx: DMX Build Compiler: gcc 4.7.2
    (II) dmx: DMX Execution OS:   Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1
    (II) dmx: DMX Execution Host: badeleux-debian
    (II) dmx: MAXSCREENS:         16
    (II) dmx: Using configuration from command line
    (II) dmx: Added 192.168.0.104:0 at 0 0
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: No Xdmx server running on backend
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Name of display: 192.168.0.104:0
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Version number:  11.0
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Vendor string:   The X.Org Foundation
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Vendor release:  11204000
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Dimensions:      1280x720 pixels
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 7 depths on screen 0:  24,1,4,8,15,16,32
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Depth of root window:  24 planes (24)
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Number of colormaps:   1 min, 1 max
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Options: backing-store no, save-unders no
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Window Manager running: yes
    (**) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: Window manager running -- colormaps not supported
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 1280x720+0+0 on 1280x720 at depth=24, bpp=32
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0x21 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff *
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc2 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc3 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc4 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc5 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc6 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc7 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc8 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xc9 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xca TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xcb TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xcc TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xcd TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xce TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xcf TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd0 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd1 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd2 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd3 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd4 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd5 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd6 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd7 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd8 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xd9 TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xda TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xdb TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xdc TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xdd TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xde TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xdf TrueColor   24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe0 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe1 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe2 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe3 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe4 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe5 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe6 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe7 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe8 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xe9 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xea DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xeb DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xec DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xed DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xee DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xef DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf0 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf1 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf2 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf3 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf4 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf5 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf6 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf7 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf8 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xf9 DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xfa DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xfb DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xfc DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xfd DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xfe DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0xff DirectColor 24b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: 0x41 TrueColor   32b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: DPMS 1.1 (on, disabled, 7200 7200 14400)
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: (request) s=1280x720+0+0 r=1280x720+0+0 @0,0 (0) (be=1280x720 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx[o0/192.168.0.104:0]: s=1280x720+0+0 r=1280x720+0+0 @0,0 (be=1280x720 depth=24 bpp=32)
    (II) dmx: Using 1280x720 as global bounding box
    (II) dmx: XSync batching with 100 ms interval
    (II) dmx: Shadow framebuffer support disabled
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: Using backend input from 192.168.0.104:0
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: Locating devices on 192.168.0.104:0 (XInputExtension version 2.2)
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    2 Virtual co XPointer        
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    3 Virtual co XKeyboard       
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    4 Virtual co XExtensionPointe
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    5 Virtual co XExtensionKeyboa
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    6 axp20-supp XExtensionKeyboa
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    7   USB Keyb XExtensionKeyboa
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    8   USB Keyb XExtensionKeyboa
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]:    9 Microsoft  XExtensionPointe
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: Added backend-mou as pointer device called Mouse0 [core]
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: Added backend-kbd as keyboard device called Keyboard0 [core]
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: XKEYBOARD: keycodes = evdev+aliases(qwerty)
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: XKEYBOARD: symbols  = pc+us+inet(evdev)
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: XKEYBOARD: geometry = pc(pc105)
    (II) dmx[i0/192.168.0.104:0]: XKEYBOARD: From device: evdev pc+us+inet(evdev) pc(pc105)
    xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003ab
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4436
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4555
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003af
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4464
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4555
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003b2
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4483
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4555
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003b7
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4504
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4555
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003c0
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4535
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4555
    (**) dmx: dmxErrorHandler: RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)
    (**) dmx:                  Major opcode: 148 (RENDER)
    (**) dmx:                  Minor opcode: 10 (RenderTrapezoids)
    (**) dmx:                  ResourceID:   0x26003ab
    (**) dmx:                  Failed serial number:  4559
    (**) dmx:                  Current serial number: 4614

    Backtrace:
    0: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (xorg_backtrace+0x49) [0xb77597f9]
    1: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0x152216) [0xb775d216]
    2: (vdso) (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0) [0xb75ec40c]
    3: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0x30cd9) [0xb763bcd9]
    4: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0xa992e) [0xb76b492e]
    5: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0x11a0e5) [0xb77250e5]
    6: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0x208d5) [0xb762b8d5]
    7: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0xb7154e46]
    8: /usr/bin/X11/Xdmx (0xb760b000+0x20c29) [0xb762bc29]

    Segmentation fault at address 0x10

    Fatal server error:
    Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting

    xinit: connection to X server lost

    waiting for X server to shut down
```

and it is correctly displayed on 192.168.0.104, despite that there are no fonts at all (no clock in bar), when I click on LXDE 'Start' Button, popup reveals but with no fonts, and when I move mouse over this popover - X crashes.

xfs works, tested from 192.168.0.104:

```
fslsfonts -server tcp/192.168.0.102:7100
-adobe-courier-bold-o-normal--0-0-100-100-m-0-iso10646-1
-adobe-courier-bold-o-normal--0-0-100-100-m-0-iso8859-1
-adobe-courier-bold-o-normal--0-0-75-75-m-0-iso10646-1
...
```

Both machines have installed debian with lxde.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the exact same symptoms... However it does not seem to be related to `xfs`.